# Filter Redis set by range of values

Tags: redis

I have a set looking like this (except that it has about 8000 items):

```
{"id":563244,"stock_id":693,"value":"9.17","symbol":"BCS"}
{"id":565527,"stock_id":10093,"value":"21.09","symbol":"GDXS"}
{"id":564311,"stock_id":4241,"value":"91.52","symbol":"NDAQ"}
{"id":565269,"stock_id":8883,"value":"127.60","symbol":"SAA"}
```

I need to be able to filter these by range of value, for example, I can say "give me all entries where value is between 5.50 and 24.36" or "give me all entries where value is between 47.45 and 301.8". There are no constraints to the numbers that can be passed to this filter.

Now, I know it's possible to create a set for each value, but I don't think that's efficient because pretty much all of the roughly 8000 entries have unique values.

If we could predefine the ranges (for example, 0-10, 10-20, etc) then I could create sets for each of these ranges, containing the keys that belong there. But alas, that is not the case and I need to make this as flexible as possible while keeping the performance solid.

I realize this may be tricky with a key-value store but maybe somebody has a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are willing to make another collection, you can use sorted set (ZSET) putting the value as scores and the entries themselves as members, like this:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> ZADD stocks 9.17 '{"id":563244,"stock_id":693,"value":"9.17","symbol":"BCS"}'
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379> ZADD stocks 21.09 '{"id":565527,"stock_id":10093,"value":"21.09","symbol":"GDXS"}' 91.52 '{"id":564311,"stock_id":4241,"value":"91.52","symbol":"NDAQ"}' 127.60 '{"id":565269,"stock_id":8883,"value":"127.60","symbol":"SAA"}'
(integer) 3
```

And then pull only the members wich have only the scores you need:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> ZRANGEBYSCORE stocks 20 100
1) "{\"id\":565527,\"stock_id\":10093,\"value\":\"21.09\",\"symbol\":\"GDXS\"}"
2) "{\"id\":564311,\"stock_id\":4241,\"value\":\"91.52\",\"symbol\":\"NDAQ\"}"
```

Comment: I think I will have to do something like this and see if the performance suffers too much!

Comment: I don't think performance would be the issue in case of a ZSET, rather the memory.

Answer (score 0):

You've got it right - searching by value in a key-value model requires wiring the value-key mapping for each value (or range). This is usually referred to as an index (not unlike what other databases do).

As an alternative, you can look into using [RediSearch](https://oss.redislabs.com/redisearch/) that was practically built just for that (among other things). It is a Redis module with an Apache+CC license.